# Updating a large number of spreadsheets using a looping script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have about 80 identical spreadsheets (destination spreadsheets) which are all based on one template and am looking for a quick way to update them all by running one script. Essentially I want the script to delete all the sheets from each destination spreadsheet then copy new versions from the template.

Through trial and error I have produced a script which will delete and copy the relevant sheets from the template into the destination spreadsheets, but it requires running on each destination spreadsheet manually (so script runs on the active sheet). I am now hoping to automate it by using another spreadsheet (Index spreadsheet) which contains a list of all the Spreadsheet IDs for the sheets which need updating. Then I would like to use a ForEach function to retrieve the Spreadsheet IDs for the destination sheets and loop that through the script.

This is the code that I have worked out so far:

```
function Update_Sheet_test() {
const Template = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1KAOgYHPHqFKhIr3Jb0Le0h9EB0VSt2Wos3l6dPY39P8");
const Source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

const Destination = Source 
  .getRange (2,6,Source.getLastRow()-1,6)
  .getValues()
  .map(SP =>[0]);

destination.forEach(function(id)
{ 

 //Make the Setup sheet visible to avoid error messages
 destination.getSheetByName("Setup Sheet").showSheet();

// This deletes all sheets from the current workbook except the ones listed 
var deleteSheets = destination.getSheets();
for (i = 0; i < deleteSheets.length; i++) {
  switch(deleteSheets[i].getSheetName()) {
  case "Setup Sheet":
  break;
  default:
  destination.deleteSheet(deleteSheets[i]);}}

//Now all the sheets from the template will be copied in turn. 
//Copy index sheet
var index_Sheet = template.getSheetByName ("Index");
index_Sheet.copyTo(destination);
destination.getSheetByName("Copy of Index").setName("Index").hideSheet();


//Copy Setup sheet (inc. copying Group information from old Setup Sheet)
var setup_Sheet_template = template.getSheetByName ("Setup Sheet");
setup_Sheet_template.copyTo(destination);
destination.getRange('\'Setup Sheet\'!D12').copyTo(destination.getRange('\'Copy of Setup 
Sheet\'!D12'),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
destination.getRange('\'Setup Sheet\'!G12').copyTo(destination.getRange('\'Copy of Setup 
Sheet\'!G12'),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);

// Delete duplicate Setup sheet
var setup_Sheet_destination = destination.getSheetByName ("Setup Sheet")
destination.deleteSheet(setup_Sheet_destination);
destination.getSheetByName("Copy of Setup Sheet").setName("Setup Sheet");

//Copy import sheet
var import_Sheet_template = template.getSheetByName ("import_Sheet");
import_Sheet_template.copyTo(destination);
destination.getSheetByName("Copy of import_Sheet").setName("import_Sheet").hideSheet();
 
//Copy Formulas sheet
var formulas = template.getSheetByName ("Formulas");
formulas.copyTo(destination);
destination.getSheetByName("Copy of Formulas").setName("formulas").hideSheet();

//Copy Main_Leaders sheet
var ml = template.getSheetByName ("Main_Leaders");
ml.copyTo(destination);
destination.getSheetByName("Copy of Main_Leaders").setName("Main_Leaders").hideSheet();

//Copy Proposed_Leaders sheet
var pl = template.getSheetByName ("Proposed_Leaders");
pl.copyTo(destination);
destination.getSheetByName("Copy of Proposed_Leaders").setName("Proposed_Leaders").hideSheet();

//Copy Assistant_Leaders sheet
var al = template.getSheetByName ("Assistant_Leaders");
al.copyTo(destination);
destination.getSheetByName("Copy of Assistant_Leaders").setName("Assistant_Leaders").hideSheet();

//Copy Group_Helpers sheet
var gh = template.getSheetByName ("Group_Helpers");
gh.copyTo(destination);
destination.getSheetByName("Copy of Group_Helpers").setName("Group_Helpers").hideSheet();

//Copy Occasional_Helpers sheet
var oh = template.getSheetByName ("Occasional_Helpers");
oh.copyTo(destination);
destination.getSheetByName("Copy of Occasional_Helpers").setName("Occasional_Helpers").hideSheet();

//Copy Trainee_Helpers sheet
var th = template.getSheetByName ("Trainee_Helpers");
th.copyTo(destination);
destination.getSheetByName("Copy of Trainee_Helpers").setName("Trainee_Helpers").hideSheet();
   
//Copy Volunteers sheet
var volunteers = template.getSheetByName ("Volunteers");
  volunteers.copyTo(destination);
destination.getSheetByName("Copy of Volunteers").setName("Volunteers");

//Copy Safer Recruitment sheet
var sr = template.getSheetByName ("Safer Recruitment");
  sr.copyTo(destination);
destination.getSheetByName("Copy of Safer Recruitment").setName("Safer Recruitment");

//Set the link from Volunteers sheet to SR Sheet
var volunteer_destination = destination.getSheetByName ("Volunteers")
var volunteer_range = volunteer_destination.getRange('D6:D6')
volunteer_range.setFormula ('=ArrayFormula(If(G6:G=\"\",\"\",ADDRESS(MATCH(F6:F,\'Safer 
Recruitment\'!E1:E,0),8,4)))');

//Copy SR overview by role sheet
var role = template.getSheetByName ("SR overview by role");
  role.copyTo(destination);
destination.getSheetByName("Copy of SR overview by role").setName("SR overview by role");

//Copy Dashboard calculations sheet
var calculations = template.getSheetByName ("Dashboard_calculations");
  calculations.copyTo(destination);
destination.getSheetByName("Copy of 
Dashboard_calculations").setName("Dashboard_calculations").hideSheet();

//Copy dashboard
    var dashboard = template.getSheetByName ("Dashboard");
        dashboard.copyTo(destination);
    destination.getSheetByName("Copy of Dashboard").setName("Dashboard")


 // Update the Index sheet which produces the links on the setup sheet (using the script 
below)
const ss = destination
const sh = ss.getSheetByName('index'); // name of the sheet where the index will be generated.
sh.getRange('A3:B30').clearContent(); // The range to be cleared


let vs = [['Sheet Name', 'Link']];
ss.getSheets().forEach(s => {
let url = Utilities.formatString('%s#gid=%s', ss.getUrl(), s.getSheetId());
vs.push([s.getName(), `${url}`]);
});
sh.getRange(3, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs); 


 // Hide the unwanted sheets
  var sheet 
 destination.getSheetByName("Index").hideSheet();
 destination.getSheetByName("Setup Sheet").hideSheet();

  })}
```

Any help you can provide would be gratefully received. Thanks

Comment: What the point of this `const Destination = Source.getRange (2,6,Source.getLastRow()-1,6).getValues().map(SP =>[0]);`

Comment: `Destination` and `destination` are the same? `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet` I believe there should be brackets `()` at the end. And I think your script can exceed time limit, by the way. Wouldn't it way simpler and faster just to copy the template 80 times instead of copying sheets from the template to each of 80 spreadsheets?

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for your assistance with this. I have used the script you mention previously to extract a set of values from a sheet to use in a looping script. In that circumstance to generate a sheet for every value in a range. I presumed that I would need to do something similar in this circumstance?

Comment: @YuriKhristich thank you for your assistance with this. I have updated the script to add the missing brackets. The reason for needing the script, and not simply copying the template is that I need a way of effectively updating the sheets periodically (when I discover for instance that a formula is no longer working) , and to save time I wanted to explore if I could do it automatically  rather than manually copying the sheets across.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? To avoid using 'ActiveSheet':

```
Dim thisSheet as Worksheet
Set thisSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(deleteSheets[i].getSheetName())
' Do stuff with thisSheet
```

Comment: Looks like Visual Basic. I suspect OP asks about Google Apps Script (which is JavaScript basically)